# unable to set CSS and click handler in jQuery after use of replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to replace normal checkbox with image. I am able to replace checkbox with image but unable to set CSS and click handler on image.

This is my jQuery code.

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.SetOnOff = function (onImage,offImage) {
         debugger;
         var html = '<img style="width: 80px; height: 30px" src="'+offImage +'"/>';
                $(this).replaceWith(html);
         $(html).css('cursor','pointer');
          $(html).click(function(){
             var fileName = $(this).attr('src');
                if (fileName == onImage)
                    $(this).attr('src', offImage);
                else
                    $(this).attr('src', onImage);
         });
                
        return  $(this);
    };
} (jQuery));
```

can anybody let me know how to do this?

you use  [This](http://jsfiddle.net/c0gsgery/) link to test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `css` and `click` methods are not being called on the replaced element but on a newly-created HTML jQuery is generating from your `html` string.

Try this instead:

```
 var $v = $("<div>" + $(this).text() + "</div>");
 $(this).replaceWith($v);
 $v.css('cursor', 'pointer');
 $v.click(function () {
     alert('a');
 });
```

Comment: I found this code works for me. Thanks haim770

Answer (score 3):

use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for dynamically created element

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var v = "<div>" + $(this).text() + "</div>";
    $(this).replaceWith(v);
    $(v).css('cursor', 'pointer');
});

$(document).on("click", "div", function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c0gsgery/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to set css to string. make it jquery object just like below

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.SetOnOff = function (onImage,offImage) {
     debugger;
     var html = $('<img style="width: 80px; height: 30px" src="'+offImage +'"/>');
            $(this).replaceWith(html);
     $(html).css('cursor','pointer');
      $(html).click(function(){
         var fileName = $(this).attr('src');
            if (fileName == onImage)
                $(this).attr('src', offImage);
            else
                $(this).attr('src', onImage);
     });

    return  $(this);
};
} (jQuery));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c0gsgery/1/)